# Commit of eclipse subversion doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

Subversion novice here, I have
Window7 64bits
eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32
jdk-7u4-windows-i586 java of 32 bits
And I follow this tutorial in order to install subversion with eclipse
http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/gettingStarted/aboutSubversive/install.php

All works fin, but subversion plugin cannot perform the commit action:
I connect with my svn server, and when i go to to java perpective y press right click -> team-> commint, Dialog Box appears, I put all required information, finally y acept and after that progress dialog appears, please help this issue is P1.

Comment: It fails without any error message?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are connecting fine, so I would try to update first then commit.  To commit a specific project, right-click on the project and SVN commit it.

What is the error you are getting?

Edit:

You might be just an unauthorized user and just have public access.  The owner might have wanted to give read access to it, but not write.

Answer (score 0):

Before being able to commit a file you have to share the project first. If you already shared the project and cannot commit a file you should get an error message telling you whats wrong.

Comment: the connection with SVN server works, even i download code from that server, but when i try to perform commit action this issue appers, and the worst is no log error or something like that

Comment: Get a command line svn client. Under windows you could use sliksvn and check if its working at all. Maybe there is a problem with your permissions.

Comment: If there is no error message, how do you know something is wrong?

Comment: @Udo Held: Eclipse has a Subversion console that shows you the command line commands and response.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with similar conditions. SVN eclipse plugins seems to be very instable  with 64 bits system (problems occured on ubuntu 64 and windows seven).

I solved these problems by installing `Slik-Subversion-1.7.7-x64` and modified `eclipse.ini` with parameters `-Djava.library.path=C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\`

This solution is provided by another poster that I have lost.